# Php Ajax and html5 form integration of contact form

Tags: php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am having experience in PHP and HTML but not much familiar with Ajax. Can anyone help me out here to integrate my contact form, please check my code below what modification can be required in PHP and ajax code. If I remove ajax its working fine after including ajax form is not getting posted

HTML Code

```
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <form action="contact.php" method="post" role="form" class="php-email-form">
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
              <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" />
              <div class="validate"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
              <div class="validate"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 8 chars of subject" />
            <div class="validate"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please write something for us" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            <div class="validate"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <div class="loading">Loading</div>
            <div class="error-message"></div>
            <div class="sent-message">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
          </div>
          <div class="text-center"><button type="submit">Send Message</button></div>
        </form>
      </div>
```

Php code

```
    <?php

      require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
      require 'send-grid/vendor/autoload.php';
      $db = new DB_Functions();

       if (isset($_POST['contact'])){

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        if ($db->storeform($name,$email,$phone,$subject,$message)) {

            $memail = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail(); 
            $memail->setFrom("info@probig.in", "Probig Consulting");
            $memail->setSubject("We have received your message");
            $memail->addTo($email);
            $raw_html = file_get_contents('email.html');
            $getvar= array('%name%');
            $repvar= array($name);
            $femail=str_replace($getvar, $repvar, $raw_html);
            $memail->addContent( "text/html", $femail);
    $sendgrid = new \SendGrid('key');
    try {
        $response = $sendgrid->send($memail);
        print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
        print_r($response->headers());
        print $response->body() . "\n";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: '. $e->getMessage() ."\n";
    }

    $email2 = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail(); 
$email2->setFrom("noreply@probig.in", "Probig Consulting");
$email2->setSubject($subject);
$email2->addTo("info@probig.in");
$email2->addContent("text/plain", "Name:".$name."<br><br>Mobile:".$phone."<br><br>Message:".$message);
$sendgrid = new \SendGrid('Key');
try {
    $response = $sendgrid->send($email2);
    print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
    print_r($response->headers());
    print $response->body() . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: '. $e->getMessage() ."\n";
}





          header("Location:msgsent.html");

          }else{


            echo "cant send message";
          }


      }




    ?>
```

AJax code:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  "use strict";

  //Contact
  $('form.php-email-form').submit(function() {

    var f = $(this).find('.form-group'),
      ferror = false,
      emailExp = /^[^\s()<>@,;:\/]+@\w[\w\.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$/i;

    f.children('input').each(function() { // run all inputs

      var i = $(this); // current input
      var rule = i.attr('data-rule');
  if (rule !== undefined) {
    var ierror = false; // error flag for current input
    var pos = rule.indexOf(':', 0);
    if (pos >= 0) {
      var exp = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
      rule = rule.substr(0, pos);
    } else {
      rule = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
    }

    switch (rule) {
      case 'required':
        if (i.val() === '') {
          ferror = ierror = true;
        }
        break;

      case 'minlen':
        if (i.val().length < parseInt(exp)) {
          ferror = ierror = true;
        }
        break;

      case 'email':
        if (!emailExp.test(i.val())) {
          ferror = ierror = true;
        }
        break;

      case 'checked':
        if (! i.is(':checked')) {
          ferror = ierror = true;
        }
        break;

      case 'regexp':
        exp = new RegExp(exp);
        if (!exp.test(i.val())) {
          ferror = ierror = true;
        }
        break;
    }
    i.next('.validate').html((ierror ? (i.attr('data-msg') !== undefined ? i.attr('data-msg') : 'wrong Input') : '')).show('blind');
  }
});
f.children('textarea').each(function() { // run all inputs

  var i = $(this); // current input
  var rule = i.attr('data-rule');

  if (rule !== undefined) {
    var ierror = false; // error flag for current input
    var pos = rule.indexOf(':', 0);
    if (pos >= 0) {
      var exp = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
      rule = rule.substr(0, pos);
    } else {
      rule = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
    }

    switch (rule) {
      case 'required':
        if (i.val() === '') {
          ferror = ierror = true;
        }
        break;

      case 'minlen':
        if (i.val().length < parseInt(exp)) {
          ferror = ierror = true;
        }
        break;
    }
    i.next('.validate').html((ierror ? (i.attr('data-msg') != undefined ? i.attr('data-msg') : 'wrong Input') : '')).show('blind');
  }
});
if (ferror) return false;
else var str = $(this).serialize();

var this_form = $(this);
var action = $(this).attr('action');

if( ! action ) {
  this_form.find('.loading').slideUp();
  this_form.find('.error-message').slideDown().html('The form action property is not set!');
  return false;
}

this_form.find('.sent-message').slideUp();
this_form.find('.error-message').slideUp();
this_form.find('.loading').slideDown();

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "contact.php",
  data: str,
  success: function(msg) {
    if (msg == 'OK') {
      this_form.find('.loading').slideUp();
      this_form.find('.sent-message').slideDown();
      this_form.find("input:not(input[type=submit]), textarea").val('');
    } else {
      this_form.find('.loading').slideUp();
      this_form.find('.error-message').slideDown().html(msg);
    }
      }
    });
    return false;
  });

});
```

Comment: The thing labeled "AJAX" in your post is a giant block of JavaScript, of which only about 20 lines are actually AJAX-related. When you say it is working fine when you don't use the AJAX, are you talking about the entire block of JavaScript, or just those 20 lines.

Comment: i am taking about if don't use entire javascript only with PHP its working

Comment: Okay, are you getting an error message?

Comment: I'm guessing you haven't got a clue what most of this JavaScript does? What do you _think_ it does? Do you think it's a good idea to include code in your page which you don't really understand? Have you made any attempt to debug it, and maybe narrow down the issue a bit more closely? Some simple debugging should allow you to identify a smaller section of code which is the root of the problem

Comment: I have read some documents on this form function but actually not getting through it because I am not much familiar with javascript and ajax.

Comment: it just keeps loading no error message

Comment: Right well including code you don't understand is a bad idea, generally! Either learn what it's for, or don't use it. For all you know, you could be including something which is a security risk.

Comment: And learn how to debug - it's almost as important a skill as the programming itself. Otherwise you'll never be able to fix anything. Familiarise yourself with your browser's Developer Tool, especially the element inspector, the console, and the network tool

Comment: We need more than just "it keeps loading". We need to know if there are any Javascript errors in the Console. We need to know if the AJAX call actually gets sent, we need to know what response, if any, came back from the server - what the status code was, and what the response body was. We need to know if it actually send the email (which you can maybe tell by doing some logging in the PHP).

Comment: P.S One thing I do notice just from reading the code is that `header("Location:msgsent.html");` makes no sense in a AJAX context - that line is a command telling the browser to redirect to another page. But AJAX calls do not respond to redirect requests, because the entire point of AJAX is to allow the user to stay on the same page, without refreshing or redirecting.

Comment: And your "success" function checks `if (msg == 'OK')`, but the PHP does not have `echo "OK";` written anywhere, so it's impossible for that `if` to ever be true.

Comment: @ADyson I am planning to learn javascript so I can include it in my projects.

Comment: Ok I get that you are learning as you go, but that means keeping it simple to begin with. This big load of code is _not_ simple. The AJAX part on its own, maybe, but the big heap of code before that? Not so much. I think it's purpose is probably to validate the form, to be honest it's way overcomplicated for that - there are much easier ways using HTML5 and some simpler javascript.

Comment: @ADyson I used header("Location:msgsent.html"); after removing ajax function form to check if php function working perfectly

Comment: ok well if you want to use AJAX then you need to remove it again. Anyway that won't directly fix your issue I don't think. Pay attention to my earlier comments about what information you need to provide before we can realistically help you.

Comment: sure I will start with some simple javascript form thanx for suggestion

Comment: hi @ADyson changed in PHP [echo "OK"]; and  in ajax as follows [type: "POST",
      url: "contact.php",
      data: datastring,
      success: function(msg)] form is getting submitted now but echo is displaying in another page instead os showing success message  can you help here

Comment: Javascript needs to prevent the default behaviour of the form (i.e. to submit) in order to let the AJAX occur. You haven't done this. Change `$('form.php-email-form').submit(function() {` to `$('form.php-email-form').submit(function(event) { event.preventDefault();` (and then put the rest of your code). See https://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/ for an explanation.